# Exclude Pages from Magento Website Restrictions

Tags: magento

We have several magento websites and some of them we would like to turn on the website restriction so only logged in customers can view it. This seems to work great except we have custom pages that we want the user to be able to access without having to login. And currently if we turn on access restriction it redirects all pages, except the login page and the password reset page, to the login page.

Does anyone know how to exclude other pages from being redirected to the login page? I think it would be a layout xml setting but I can't seem to figure it out or find anything on it.

Magento Enterprise version 1.12.02

Answer (score 4):

Wow, this question is pretty valid, rather old, ranked high on on Google results, yet without a good answer. So here goes one.

The right way to exclude pages from restriction is by adding them to `generic` list of pages under Enterprise_WebsiteRestriction module config.

See `app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/etx/config.xml` and `config/frontend/enterprise/websiterestriction` section in particular. Pages under `full_action_names/generic` are always accessible no matter what restriction level is set. Those in `full_action_names/register` are still accessible when restriction mode is set to "Login and Register" - i.e. they are intended for new registration to be possible.

The values under those sections are full actions names (i.e. `<module>_<controller>_<action>`), so e.g. to enable contact form for everyone, you need to add `contacts_index_index` to the `generic` list.

Note that editing files in core codepool is strongly discouranged, so to achieve this it's best to create your own module and add the configuration section.

It should look somewhat like this (remember to enable this module in `app/etc/modules`):

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Emki_WebsiteUnrestrict>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Emki_WebsiteUnrestrict>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <enterprise>
            <websiterestriction>
                <full_action_names>
                    <generic>
                        <contacts_index_index />
                    </generic>
                </full_action_names>
            </websiterestriction>
        </enterprise>
    </frontend>
</config>`

Comment: I like the looks of this answer. Will be trying it soon and thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nick,There are several process for this function...

Step1:you can it from Controllers from using dispatch event.

```
 /**
     * Retrieve customer session model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }
 public function preDispatch()
    {
        // a brute-force protection here would be nice

        parent::preDispatch();

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            return;
        }

        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
/* put all action of this controllers  for check ,if any actions of list is exit then redirect to  login page*/
        $openActions = array(
            'index',
            'post',
            'autoy',
            'confirmation'
        );
        $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

        if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
            if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
                $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Action postdispatch
     *
     * Remove No-referer flag from customer session after each action
     */
    public function postDispatch()
    {
        parent::postDispatch();
        $this->_getSession()->unsNoReferer(false);
    }
```

Other thing is Using observer